# open all csv in a folder one by one and append them to a dictionary or pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pandas

I have data save as csv in a folder. I would like to open them and create a unique dictionary or dataframe to work with it. the data have the same column name but different number of row. 
I have tried

```
big_data={}
path='/pathname'
files=glob.glob(path+/".csv")
for l in files:
   data=pd.read_csv(l,index_col=None, header=0)
   big_data.append(data)
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(big_data)
```

but the result is not good at all
can anyone give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a list and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat):

```
big_data=[]
path='/pathname'
files=glob.glob(path+/".csv")
for l in files:
   data=pd.read_csv(l,index_col=None, header=0)
   big_data.append(data)
df=pd.concat(big_data)
```

the problem with the [`from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) approach is that it's expecting the keys to be either indices or columns, but in your case they are df objects which is incorrect

Comment: thank you! if I do some sub-setting to the data frame before appending it would it still work?

Comment: You mean selecting the same columns for each df? yes you can do this using the `usecols` param to `read_csv` or pass the same list of columns to the df before appending

Comment: thank you! I did some calculation and added a new column but it still works